# Accentuated characters proposition like MACOSX

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, macosx

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to have the proposition of accented characters such as the one available under OSX.

Indeed on OSX when you want to put an accent, you can just hold down the button (e for example) and a list of accented characters present on this letter appears on screen like so:

[image]
[image]

We can found documentation of this feature on OSX website [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586), and I did not find an equivalent GNU / Linux currently.

It's always about character sequence (like `Alt+144`).

Hence my question: is there an equivalent?